# .htaccess RewriteCond REQUEST_FILENAME

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my .htaccess file created from a third party (vBSEO):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(admincp|modcp|clientscript|cpstyles|images)/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ vbseo.php [L,QSA]
```

Why is the third line ("if REQUEST is not this particular directory") needed if I have already determined that the directory does not exist with line 2?  Doesn't line two state, "if the request is not a directory"?

Answer (score 3):

The second line does indeed mean "requested filename is not a physical directory". The third line, however, means "requested filename does not contain any of the sequences /admincp/ or /modcp/ etc". You see, it's a regular expression, and since it doesn't use the anchors `^` (denoting start of string) or `$` (denoting end of string), it matches any strings that merely *contain* these directory names.

So the .htaccess says that we should redirect any requests to vbseo.php if it's not for an existing resource and the requested filename isn't in any of those directories. `/admincp/index.html` won't be redirected (supposing that index.html exists). Note that `/foo/bar/admincp/baz/qux` won't be redirected either.

Comment: Well, if the request is "not for an existing resource" then "the requested filename [can't be] in any of those directories", so my question remains:  Why ensure that the request is not in any of those directories if it doesn't even exist?

And "/admincp/index.html won't be redirected" even supposing that index.html _doesn't_ exist.

Comment: Haha!   Yeah, I got an alert that this question had been viewed 2500 times, so I looked at it again and forgot why this answer made sense.  :)

Comment: I had to wrap my head around the wording too. What was I thinking. BUT I wrote it at four in the morning, sooooo...

Answer (score 1):

The first two lines do ensure that no request gets redirected to vbseo.php if the request is the name of an existing file or directory.  However, the third line ensures that requests do not get redirected even if they do *not* exist if they include /(admincp|...)/.

More importantly though, the third line allows for *resources* that are not files or directories to be served after the vbseo redirect.

```
RewriteRule ^blogs$ blogorama.php [L]
```

if /blogs/ is not accessible via the file system for example.